# Can't iterate through an ArrayList of Objects using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have an ArrayList of Objects that I instantiated from the follow [class file](http://pastebin.com/2V4PPAV2). I am calling the bean here;

```
<jsp:useBean id="myCart" class="beans.ShoppingCart"></jsp:useBean>
```

I am trying to iterate through them using JSTL like so;

```
    <c:forEach items="${beans.ShoppingCart.cartItems}" var="tr">
            <tr>
                <td>${tr.ID}</td
                <td>${tr.Description}</td>
                <td>${tr.Category}</td>
                <td>${tr.Price}</td>
                <td>${tr.Name}</td>
            </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

But nothing is showing up on the the page. What is the correct syntax to iterate through these objects? Here is the [class file](http://pastebin.com/tXNLV53K) with the TableRow Objects. I know the array list is being populate because the Netbeans debugger shows the TableRows and their properties inside the array list.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<jsp:useBean id="myCart" class="beans.ShoppingCart">` creates a new instance of the `ShoppingCart` class, and assigns it to variable `myCart`. It is the JSP equivalent of:

```
ShoppingCart myCart = new ShoppingCart();
```

**Notice that the shopping cart is empty, since you never call `setCartItems()`.**

To iterate the list of cart items, do this:

```jsp
<c:forEach var="item" items="${myCart.cartItems}">
    <tr>
        <td>${item.ID}</td>
        <td>${item.Description}</td>
        <td>${item.Category}</td>
        <td>${item.Price}</td>
        <td>${item.Name}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Okay. I don't want to instantiate a new object, I want to use the EXISTING object in the session that the Servlet is updating. How do I do that? The code above doesn't show anything.

Comment: @CryptoJones If you already have the shopping cart stored as a session attribute, then just use it by name, meaning remove the `<jsp:useBean>` line and use the session attribute name in the `<c:forEach>` loop.

Comment: That still didn't work. I've tried myCart, beans.ShoppingCart and even beans.ShoppingCart.cartItems. I don't understand why. I even tried getting the session attribute like this; http://pastebin.com/XYq4x6NT

Comment: You said you *"want to use the EXISTING object in the session"*. That would imply that you have code putting the object into the session, using some name. Where is that code, and what name did you give the session attribute?

Comment: Sorry, I am just really confused. I am instantiating it in the Admin controller  here; http://pastebin.com/5pGiPS0T

Comment: You were right, I was instantiating "result" in my controller by not "myCart". Thanks for the help!